Removing rubbery tape from painted window frame
After removing some broken window blinds which had metal rails taped to the sides of the window frames, I'm left with some rubbery black tape, which sticks very strongly to the painted frame. I want to remove this.
What I've tried so far:

Scraping off the tape cleanly with my fingers and finger nails is possible, but extremely tedious and time-consuming. I spent 30 minutes doing about 30 cm, and I've got about 10 metres to do in total, so I'd prefer a more efficient method that is less harsh on my fingers.
Isopropanol and cleaning benzine had no effect at all.
Applying heat with a hot air gun had no effect at all.
Various metal tools tend to damage the paint and/or wood.
I tried an old credit card and some plastic cutlery, but it wasn't effective on the tape.
Dremel with a polishing bit quickly removes the tape, but easily damages the paint even at low speed.



Did you try applying a heat gun and then using a plastic scraper?  Personally, I don't think you're going to get out of here without having to do some repainting.  Might have to use powered equipment to remove the foam, then smooth and repaint.

I did try scraping after applying heat, that went about as well as scraping without heat. I understand repainting may ultimately be necessary for a good result, but this is a rental property that will have to be repainted when I move out in 1-2 years, so I was planning just to accept any minor damage at the moment rather than repainting. Still don't want to leave the tape in place or strip paint on the whole length.

In the meantime I've found that some sections are much easier to remove by hand than the one I tried first, so I'm back to that method. But some parts do resist a lot.

The sticky "glue" of the tape is what holds the tape to the paint of the frame. Attack the glue and the tape will come off.
But the rubber surface of the tape hides the glue from whatever treatment will remove the glue. So the surface needs to be scraped away. Here are two ideas:

Use a sharp razor in a razor holder to cut between the tape's glue and rubber surface. (Yes, the report is that metal tools damage the paint. That means the tools aren't being used carefully enough.) Once the plastic surface is removed, then use new tape to remove the "glue" of the old tape. Tape removes tape: the "sticky" of new tape pulls on the sticky of the old tape. Press new tape over the old tape's glue and rip away the new tape fast. Some of the old glue will come up. Repeat until the old glue has been pulled away.

Fall back and punt: Get the tape off any way it comes off fast, even if the paint is damaged, then sand, prime, and re-paint the trim. (The paint is reported damaged already, and the whole frame may need a re-paint to cover the present damage anyway, so further damage is much of a muchness.)


